# gnuplot - "autotitle coloumnhead" key and datafile with "#"

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need your help with gnuplot. Right now, I use this little script, to plot the data below.

The problem is, that gnuplot dont recognize the header line because of the comment char '#'. I can not simply remove the char, because this is "live data" that is overwritten every 10 sec.

So, my question is: How can I use autotile with a commented out header line?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set terminal pdf
set output "./postProcessing/residuals/residuals.pdf"
datafile = "./postProcessing/residuals/0/residuals.dat"
set datafile commentschars "%"
set key autotitle columnhead
set log y
set title "Residuals"
set ylabel ''
set xlabel 'Time'
set format y "%g"
set grid
plot for [col=2:7] datafile using 1:col with lines title columnheader
```

residuals.dat

```
# Residuals   
# Time          p               Ux              Uy          
1               1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
2               1.674960e-02    1.083190e-01    5.252060e-01
3               1.248170e-02    2.371500e-01    5.734970e-01
4               1.045440e-02    2.629550e-01    3.115170e-01
5               1.206470e-02    2.247980e-01    2.269900e-01
6               1.593340e-02    1.416050e-01    5.493240e-01
7               5.426080e-02    3.922100e-02    5.199160e-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  set datafile commentschars "%" is the correct way to switch to a different comment character.  However in your case both the first and second line in the file start with #.  You want it to skip line 1 and use line 2 and can no longer do this on the basis of the leading character.  So instead you must make the skip explicit.  Furthermore, since the # at the start of line 2 is no longer a comment indicator then it will be interpreted as a column header. So you need to shift the titles by one column.  So your new command is

```
plot for [col=2:7] datafile skip 1 using 1:col with lines title columnheader(col+1)
```

Comment: I forgot about that "skip command" - thank you very much and have a nice weekend.